# Jscrollpane mousedrag not working in popup on opera 12.12

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Here is my code snippet. This code is working correctly in every browser even in IE all versions except opera 12.12 and above

$(function() {
jQuery(".footer_right li a").click(function(event){ var pop=jQuery(this).attr('href'); pop=pop.substr(pop.lastIndexOf('#'),pop.length); $('.popup').hide(); jQuery(pop+',.popup_section').fadeIn('slow',function() { scrollpane = $(pop).jScrollPane({showArrows: true, scrollbarWidth : '20'}).data().jsp; }); if(event.preventDefault()) event.preventDefault(); else event.returnValue = false; return false; }); });

Please use the below URL for live example:
http://wordpress.markupbox.com/vidit_new1/

You need to scroll down to the bottom of the page and cleck on privacy to open a pop up

Please help.
Thanks in advance